# Set random global color from array with Nuxt on page load

Tags: vue.js, random, vuex, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt app, I want to set a global random color from an array on page load. It should remain the same while browsing the page and only change on hard page reload.

I am a Vue/Nuxt beginner but have so far understood that I probably should set this up with a Vuex store. The color only needs to be set/mutated once (when the website is first loaded). But I am stuck with figuring out the right code, and the right place to first set the variable (on the landing page? In the layout page used for the landing page? In the Vuex store? ...).

I have so far come up with a mixin that picks a random number:

## mixins/globalColor.js

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            list: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'pink', 'orange'],
            globalColor: ''
        }
    },
    created() {
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.list.length)
        this.globalColor = this.list[randomColor]
    }
}
```

Any pointers on how to turn `globalColor` into a global state and where best to run this? Thanks a lot in advance!

---

## Edit

I came up with the following code, which correctly chooses a random number from an array and sets it as a state:

## Store (store/index.js)

```js
export const state = () => ({
    list: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'pink', 'orange'],
    globalColor: 'lightgrey' //default value
})

export const mutations = {
    setGlobalColor(state) {
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * state.list.length)
        state.globalColor = state.list[randomColor]
    }
}

export const getters = {
    get(state) {
        return state.globalColor
    }
}
```

## Setting the state (where?)

```js
import { mapState, store } from 'vuex'

store,
methods: {
    setGlobalColor() {
        this.$store.commit('setGlobalColor')
    }
},
fetch({ store }) {
    store.commit('setGlobalColor')
},
computed: mapState(['globalColor'])
```

## Getting the state (mixins/page.js)

```js
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['get']),
    getGlobalColor() {
        return this.$store.state.globalColor
    }
}
```

Now, the only problem is to **make the "set" snippet work in the right place**. If I put it on a regular page, everything works, except of course that the store is set only if I call *that* page. But it should be set on first page load, regardless of which page I call. I tried putting it in my default layout, however, it doesn't work, even I used identical code.

Here is my complete **default layout** code (without styling):

## layouts/default.vue

```js
<template>
    <div class="base">
        <div class="page">
            <SiteTitle />
            <nuxt />
        </div>
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, store } from 'vuex'
import SiteTitle from '@/components/SiteTitle.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        SiteTitle,
        Footer
    },
    store,
    head() {
        return {
            bodyAttrs: {
                class: 'color-mode'
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setGlobalColor() {
            this.$store.commit('setGlobalColor')
        }
    },
    fetch({ store }) {
        store.commit('setGlobalColor')
    },
    computed: mapState(['globalColor']),
    mounted() {
        console.log('globalColor state:', this.globalColor)
    }
}
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you don't want to use vuex, you can use `Vue.observable` ! I took the tip from that blog (it is the guy from `vee-validate`) https://logaretm.com/tips/, or the official doc: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a great alternative. However did I manage to get the Vuex store working in the meantime, now it's only a matter on where to set it, so I'd like to stick with the Vuex solution for now (also cause it's a great lesson for me to learn Vuex). Edited my original post with the new code and final question.